# How to stylize the EqualTo Validator message in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have the validator

`EqualTo('pass_confirm', message='Passwords Must Match!')`

which when the passwords don't match shows an error like this.

How do I stylize the error message to be red? I've already tried changing the message to a `<span style="color:red">`, but it renders plain text and not the HTML.

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

Flask provides an error element in your form for you. To be able to use it, include the following on your template:

Generic example:

```
 {{ form.password.label }}<br>
 {{ form.password(size=32) }}<br>
 {% for error in form.password.errors %}
 <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah I saw this too, but then I can't use `wtforms`. I guess `wtforms` just doesn't support it.

Comment: Have you tried using FlaskForm? It uses WTForms and allows you to write the above code